# Application C# image quality

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I am developing an application with C#. In the application I developed, I take the picture file with the user selection and transfer the picture onto the form.

After this step, I want to make changes to the bitmap of the picture. For example resizing the image in small sizes and converting to 1bpp color format.

I can do these now, I can resize the image and convert it to 1bpp color format, but at this point I think I have quality problems.

For example, when I take a screenshot of a text and send it to the program, I see that the letters in the text are unclearly bad when I view it in the resized 1bpp color format.

I show the algorithms I used and the screenshot of the application:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ResizeImage.filePath);
Bitmap bmpOriginalRGB = Helper.ImageResize(bmp, 512, 384);
pcbox1.Image = bmpOriginalRGB;

Bitmap bmpResizeRGB = Helper.ImageResize(bmp, ResizeWidth, ResizeHeight);
pcbox2.Image = bmpResizeRGB;

Bitmap bmpResize1BPP_1 = Helper.ConvertTo1BppImage(Helper.ImageResize(bmp, ResizeWidth, ResizeHeight));
pcbox3.Image = bmpResize1BPP_1;

Bitmap bmpResize1BPP_2 = bmpResizeRGB.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, ResizeWidth, ResizeHeight), PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
pcbox4.Image = bmpResize1BPP_2;
Bitmap oledBitmap = bmpResize1BPP_2;
```

and

```
public static Bitmap ImageResize(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
    {
        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
            graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
        }
    }
    return destImage;
}
```

[Here's a first screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgnan.jpg)
[Here's a second screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLZ89.jpg)
[Here's a third screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWp98.jpg)

For example, as in the second screen image, the shadow of the woman appears as black. And I don't want that. I want to see a clearer black and white image.

Do you think it is possible to further improve this picture quality?

Edit: Sorry for translate..

Comment: Why do you want to use 1bpp?

Comment: You already posted this question [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973974/application-about-c-sharp-image-quality). Deleting and reposting a closed question is a violation of community rules. Do not do that. When your question is closed, your job is to [edit _that_ question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63973974/edit) to fix the problems that led to its closure in the first place, and then wait for the community to evaluate it again. If you have improved it enough, it will be reopened.

Comment: If your issue is with the conversion to 1bpp, you should really add the actual function that's doing that. You posted the `ImageResize` one but not the `ConvertTo1BppImage` one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe your problem is the quality on resizing,  it's rather the conversion from greyscale to black and white.

When resizing, the color of the adjacent pixels are averaged together to get a new color approximating the set of pixels.   So going from a 200x200 pixel image to a 100x100 pixel image, a set of 4 pixels becomes a single pixel.  It will still look fairly good, but the solid black text will become a series of gray pixels.   The exact formula will vary by the interpolation method used.  But when resizing a nice piece of black and white text, the text will end up lighter or more grey (which will be important later)

However, when going from greyscale (or full color) to black and white each pixel ends up being either black and white,  there are no other options, but there are different algorithms used to decide which pixels end up black or white, often called dithering. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither)

Your first b/w image appears to use some form of error diffusion, quite possibly Floyd-Steinberg.   It tends to work fairly well on real wold images and turns grey areas into spaced out black pixels visually approximating the greyness of the area they fall in.

Your second b/w image appears to be a simple threshold algorithm.  Basically pixels darker than a certain color end up black, and all the rest end up white.   You can adjust the image by simply setting which color is used as the threshold.  Often this works well with text, but you will need to adjust the value used as the threshold, but I don't know if the libraries you are using allow for this or not.  I have found what works well for programmatically selecting the threshold is to total up how many pixels there are of each color, and then assume some percent will be black (text tends to be mostly white space), then choose the threshold that gives you that number of black pixels.

And there are many other dithering algorithms that you can try, as well as edge detection algorithms.  You can also try adjusting the contrast of the image before converting to b/w.

However, at the end of the day, when resolution is low (pixels per character), it may not be possible to easily convert them to b/w and have them still be readable (just try to fax small text on a fax machine in standard mode).   Remember your resize removed a lot of information and the conversion from 8 bit to 1 bit removed another 87% of the information in the resized picture.